# Objects with relations in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have recently started doing object oriented javascript and have come across a need to connect two objects to each other.

What this code does is that it creates a company-object. and based on information from that company-object it creates a new object called person (it's a contact-person).

```
search.parseresults(function(announcementID){
    //query every single page
    var myCompany = new company(announcementID);
    myCompany.requestPage(function(){
        //on response parse the data.
        myCompany.parsedata()
        var myPerson = new person(myCompany.company.contact.firstname, myCompany.company.contact.lastname, myCompany.company.contact.postal, myCompany.company.contact.adress )
        myPerson.getPhone(function(){
            //console.log(myPerson)
            //myPerson.save();
        });
    })
});
```

Inside the contact I need to access some of the data from the company-object. Currently I pass it as arguments and the save it to the person-object.

```
function person(firstname, lastname, postal, adress){
    this.attempt = 0
    this.firstname = firstname
    this.lastname = lastname
    this.postal = postal
    this.adress = adress
}
```

But this feels like a bad approach. What are the best practices for referencing objects from within eachother? I have several company and person objects running in paralell.

Comment: Would you provide us with more information please? The complete code would be very helpful. Perhaps you could create a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ "Create a new Fiddle - jsFiddle").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use something like a "static method":

```
person.fromCompanyContact = function (company) {
  return new person(company.contact.first_name, ...)
}
```

So in the callback it would be:

```
....
var myPerson = person.fromCompanyContact(myCompany.company);
....
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's better to refer directly to object's property, that pass property as arg.

Like:
this.address = referObj.prop;